# $.when not working as I would expect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please see the JavaScript below:

```
function LoadAjax(){
    $.when(Possibles()) //Display Possibles first
        .done(function () {
            //alert('Possibles complete);
            GetSQLTable();
            LinkedUSNs();
        })
}
```

I expect Possibles to complete and all the information to appear on the webpage before `GetSQLTable` and `LinkedUSNs` start.  However, this does not happen. The information from `GetSQLTable` appears first.  However, if I add an alert box (currently commented out in the code above), then it works.  Why is this?

`Possibles()`, `GetSQLTable()` and `LinkedUSNs()` return HTML tables to the webpage via AJAX (JQuery).

Comment: Presumably `Possibles()` doesn't return a promise, but you haven't provided enough code to say any more than that.

Comment: Convention in JavaScript programming is to use function names beginning with capital letters only for constructor functions (i.e. those which are intended to be used with `new`). I recommend renaming your functions.

Comment: @Quentin: While that's true, capitalization conventions have absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the entire code. You might want to check the current state of the Deferred object in your promise (`Possibles()` function):

```
    $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        // debug
        console.log(deferred.state());
    });
```

Or you can call resolved in your promise (which would call any `doneCallbacks` added by `deferred.then()` or `deferred.done()`):

```
    $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        // dom ready?
        $(deferred.resolve);
    });
```